# laravel scheduler executes jobs 2 hours later (I guess problem is UTC on the server)

Tags: debian, scheduler, utc, laravel-7

I am trying to execute job daily at certain time, but it is always executed 2 hours later.
The job just writes a log.

If I use this scheduler:

```
$schedule->job(new MyJob)->dailyAt('10:00');
```

The log is always written at 12:00AM.

I have a vps with debian, and the result of the `date` command on the server is right.
I tried to change the file `/etc/adjtime` from `UTC` to `LOCAL` without success.

Comment: In config/app.php is a setting `'timezone' => 'UTC',` so i would assume the system timezone does not affect anything in laravel. You could specify a timezone when scheduling the job like `$schedule->job(new MyJob)->dailyAt('10:00')->timezone('America/Chicago');`

Comment: @RolandStarke I changed the value in config/app.php and it worked, even if in the log I write the php date and it writes 2 hours before. Is it normal?

Comment: Hey, sorry, i am a very superficial programmer and have actually no clue about anything. I would not think that its normal when logging with date('Y-m-d H:i:s ') or DateTime or Carbon. I would assume it shows 10:00. When changing in app.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Roland Starke comment I solved changing the value in `config/app.php`:

From:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

To:

```
 'timezone' => 'my timezone',
```